# Bootstrap jQuery - Set radio button back to default checked

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I have the following structure in HTML:

```
<div id="RadioGroup" class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input id="RadioGroupYes" type="radio" class="toggle" value="true" />Yes
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default active">
    <input id="RadioGroupNull" type="radio" class="toggle" checked="checked" value="null" />-
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input id="RadioGroupNo" type="radio" class="toggle" value="false" />No
  </label>
</div>
```

And I have a button that is meant to reset everything to default, which works except the `$('#RadioGroupNull').prop('checked', true);` line.  There are no errors in the console, it simply does nothing upon clicking this.

What am I missing when it comes to changing back to the default checked radio button?

JQuery Code:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('#RadioGroupNull').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Can you post Jquery code?

Comment: To explain to you why your code isn't working first we need to see your ([MCVE]) code. You need to show your JavaScript/jQuery for us to help you.

Comment: I did:  `$('#RadioGroupNull').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: That is only one line of your code.  If that line is in a click handler, post the entire handler.  I.e., there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the one line that you posted, so we need more clues.

Comment: Not sure if that makes a difference because everything else (as I mentioned already) runs fine on that click without any error and I get no error messages from this line either.

Comment: Have you tried putting this in your code to see if the button click is detected ? alert("My message.");

Comment: Yes, that works fine as I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my problem like this:

```
<div id="RadioGroup" class="btn-group">
  <label id="RadioGroupYes" class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="true" />Yes
  </label>
  <label id="RadioGroupNull" class="btn btn-default active">
    <input type="radio" class="toggle" checked="checked" value="null" />-
  </label>
  <label id="RadioGroupNo" class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="false" />No
  </label>
</div>
```

As you can see I moved all the id's from the inputs to the labels surrounding them.

Then I used the following JQuery functions on the reset button click:

```
$('#RadioGroupYes').removeClass('active');
$('#RadioGroupNo').removeClass('active');
$('#RadioGroupNull').addClass('active');
```

This all worked perfectly on the form input submission too.  All tested.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a name attribute to the three buttons, something like this:

```
<div id="RadioGroup" class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input id="RadioGroupYes" type="radio" name="myRadios" class="toggle" value="true" />Yes
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default active">
    <input id="RadioGroupNull" type="radio" name="myRadios" class="toggle" checked="checked" value="null" />-
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input id="RadioGroupNo" type="radio" name="myRadios" class="toggle" value="false" />No
  </label>
</div>

<button id="button">OK</button>
```

Then when you click on one button, the others get cleared.  With the name attribute in place, a click handler like you've shown (plus a closing parenthesis and semicolon), will set it back to the default null button:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('#RadioGroupNull').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't working either, still not showing any errors for me.

Comment: That is why we need to see more of your code.  If you put only what I have (along with including jQuery), it should work--it works for me in IE, Firefox, and Chrome.